# Recursive Back tracking in a maze in java

Tags: java

Hi im new to the site so sorry if this is a repeat question but none of the previous questions seemed to match mine

I'm practising search algorithms within a maze structure and my attempt at a recursive backtracking is not working

Basically I have followed a exercise on a book Dietel volume 7 to create a maze and use recursion to find the solution but all my code does is:

- finds the start position.
- gets to the next position
- then says there is no other move and exits the program

This is my method its know its bulky but im still working on it

```
public boolean mazeTraversal( char maze2[][], int x, int y)
{
   lastX = x;
   lastY = y;
   maze[ x ][ y ] = 'x';
   printMaze();
   showPosition();
   showMoves();
   System.out.println("Press the key 'g' to traverse the maze : ");
   move++;

   if((x == Y_START) && (x == X_START) && (move > 1))
   {
         System.out.println("You have gone back to the start");
         return false;
   }
   else if ( mazeExited( x, y ) && ( move > 1 ) )
   {
       System.out.println("You have reached the end");
       return true;
   }

   else
   {
       char response = scanner.nextLine().charAt( 0 );
       showPosition();
       showMoves();
       System.out.println( "Enter 'g' to continue, 'e' to exit: " );

       if(response == 'e')
       {
           System.exit(0);
       }

       if(response == 'g') 
           while(checkMaze(x,y) == validMove(x,y) && checkMaze(x,y)!= mazeExited(x,y))
           {
               for(int count = 0; count < 4; count++)
               {
                   switch (count)
                   {
                       case (DOWN):
                           if ( validMove( x + 1, y ) ) 
                           {
                               mazeTraversal(maze2, x + 1, y);
                           }
                           break;

                       case (RIGHT):
                           if ( validMove( x, y + 1 ) ) 
                           {
                             mazeTraversal( maze2, x, y + 1 );
                           }
                           break;

                       case (UP): // move up
                           if ( validMove( x - 1, y ) ) 
                           {
                               mazeTraversal( maze2, x - 1, y );
                           }
                         break;

                       case (LEFT): // move left
                           if ( validMove( x, y - 1 ) ) 
                           {
                               mazeTraversal( maze2, x, y - 1 );
                           }            
                 }
               }
             }
           }
     return false;
```

}

Any pointers would be great.
Thanks Mike

Comment: Did you try to trace your code, see where it goes wrong? Actually noone's gonna do this for you, so you should debug first, then come back with a more specific question, if you'd want to. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ill note the problem more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider returning your recursive calls to mazeTraversal() in your else block, instead of returning false.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply gonna break it down and build it up again.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1) What is the purpose of maze2 ? You never use it or change it. Perhaps you should remove maze2 as a parameter and just update/reference maze[][] instead?

2) There is no exit condition. Even when one recursive call reaches the end and returns true, the success message will display and then the program will continue attempting to traverse the maze.

3) There are multiple things wrong with the while loop. For one, the condition will always evaluate as true. It does not look like you break or return out of the loop at all )but you have a few missing braces so I might be wrong).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply gonna break it down and build it up again